# Auth.js: way to get oauth permission to manage youtube user playlist in providers/google

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, youtube, next-auth

When using [auth.js](https://authjs.dev/reference/core/providers_google) in my sveltekit application:

```
Google({
    clientId: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, 
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET, 
})
```

I am able to get users name/email, on oauth user acknowledge that my app would have access to account name/email.

I would like to know if there is a option to request more permissions for example view/edit permision to youtube playlists. My application would like to give user ability to manage their youtube playlists.

I enabled `YouTube Data API v3` to my project and added   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube to OAuth consent screen.

Adding

```
authorization: { params: { scope: "openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl" } },
```

will result in error when user selects the gmail account.

I would appreciate any help.